# vim-arline-themes can't set theme

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

I have my `.vimrc` as

```
set nocompatible 
filetype off

syntax on
set nu

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

I want to select an AirlineTheme e.g.

```
:AirlineTheme molokai
```

Unfortunately the theme is not applied and vim editor stays visually the same with no change. I use Ubuntu 14.04. I wonder what's wrong. Somehow GNOME terminal should be set prior to vim being used?

Note:
VIM

```
r59400@Latitude:~$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
```

Terminal

```
GNOME Terminal 3.6.2
A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop
```

Comment: The command `AirlineTheme` is not available after the vimrc file has been load. You need to put it into an `VimEnter` autocommand or set the theme manually, like this `:let g:airline_theme='dark'`. BTW: This is all in the documentation. You should read it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set AirlineTheme e.g.
>
> `:ArlineTheme molokai`

Seems you made a mistake, shouldn't it be `:AirlineTheme molokai`

Also try setting it in vimrc and see if the problem persists. To set it in your .vimrc, use:

```
let g:airline_theme='<theme>'
```

e.g.

```
let g:airline_theme='simple'
```

Comment: you're right it's typo; it should be :AirlineTheme molokai; anyway I did set as you suggested and problem persists...

Comment: give `set t_Co=256` (in .vimrc)  a try :D

Comment: with that set no change

Comment: does any other theme work ?

Comment: nope, other themes are not working...

Comment: i just used Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes' and able to change it e.g.; :colorscheme molokai

Comment: Oh great !! . Seems like airline-themes installation didnt go well.

Comment: anyway to fix airline-themes?